Raspberry Pi 5 IBSS AD-HOC Wifi network using nmcli or nmtui (no graphic interface)
I need to create an ad-hoc network with several Raspberry Pi 5. No DHCP required (each will have an static IP) and also no default route (I need IBSS  mode, as the wifi network will be used just to interconnect the raspberrys)
All examples I find are for older hardware and OS. How can I do that in Bookworm Raspberry OS? I have tried using nmtui shell tool but no success.
I am getting auth errors:
When I use nmcli as in
nmcli connection modify adhoc-network ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.1/24

but I get:
802.1X supplicant took too long to authenticate

Then I modify it to ensure it does not use 802.1x doing
nmcli connection modify adhoc-network 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt none

getting
Passwords or encryption keys are required to access the wireless network 'adhoc-network'

So I try:
nmcli connection modify adhoc-network 802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt none

but get:
Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided


Do you mean "ad-hoc" as in IBSS, or do you mean "ad-hoc" as in "no dedicated router"? Do you need WPA2 security or do you want an open network?

Thanks @grawity. I don't know the difference between both "ad-hoc". IBSS is "a wireless configuration where devices communicate directly with each other without a central device like a router or access point." so I am not sure the difference with "no dedicated router". On the other hand, initially I don't need security as it's for testing but ultimately I will need to secure the ad-hoc network. Thanks for any way forward..

By "no dedicated router" I meant "one of the RPi units would be the access point and everything else would connect to it". But it sounds like you're looking for IBSS mode then?

Thnka @grawity. Yes, I don't want one of the RPi nits to become access point but get them to link using the IBSS mode. As mentioned, using the nmtui generates an authentication issue (question edited to clarify)

Do you have NetworkManager 1.22.0 or later? That seems to be the first version with support for "IBSS-RSN" (IBSS with WPA2). Does the system use 'wpa_supplicant' or 'iwd' as NM's Wi-Fi backend (check the process list)? Although for a 'headless' system I'd probably suggest plain wpa_supplicant without NM...

i am using Raspberry PIs 5 (built-in Wifi hardware) with last version Raspberry OS (Bookworm). All packages updated. I guess that should be using latest Networkmanager. What I am not sure is if builtin Wifi hardware in the RBP 5 support ad-hoc.
